# Can we obtain a Hadamard matrix as sum of two matrices of decaying singular values?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, svd

Is there a kind of matrices in $[-1,1]^{n\times n}$ that, when we sum two of them, we obtain a Hadamard matrix of order $n$ (assumed that $n$ is $1$, $2$ or divisible by $4$) as their sum?

For example, we can obtain a (more general) matrix $S\in\{-1,1\}^{m\times n}$ as a sum of two matrices $A,B\in[-1,1]^{m\times n}$ by defining $B=A-1_{m\times n}$.

**Edit**: As I made some progress on understanding the basic problem I face, I'm able to specify my question much more. I'm specifically trying to express a Hadamard matrix of order $n$ as a sum of two matrices $A,B\in[-1,1]^{n\times n}$ such that at least one of them must have decaying singular values (i.e., it's $k$ last singular values, for $k=1,\dots ,m \, , m\ll n$, according to their ordering, must have a very small magnitude, nearly close to zero).

Comment: The question may need clarification. Starting from any Hadamard matrix $S$ surely there are many ways to write $S$ as a sum, even of matrices whose entries are all in $\{-1,0,1\}$ ?

Comment: Yes, there is, i.e., the collection of such pairs is nonempty. But what are you really looking for besides examples?

Comment: If I were to write a Hadamard matrix as a sum of two matrices in an obvious way, i.e. when $A,B\in \{-1,0,1\}$ or by writing the Hadamard matrix as a sum of rank 1 matrices via SVD, then grouping and adding the terms, I'd rather do it by myself than asking for such a way. I ask for one or more nontrivial ways to do it. Any example would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think you should make explicit what constitutes an acceptable answer. If you ask a question that has a trivial correct answer then you cannot in good faith reject that answer - unless you enumerate the unacceptable ones up front already in the question. This is true regardless whether a bounty is offered or not.

Comment: @Justpassingby Excuse me in case that you found my comment somehow rude. I just thought that most users might understand that I'm not looking for a simple answer. You're right from your point of view. So, I edited my question in order to state the problem much more rigorously.

Comment: Much clearer. Is a singular value the same as an eigenvalue?

Comment: A singular value of a matrix corresponds to an eigenvalue of it and it is equal to the square root of this eigenvalue. If you want, have a look on this wikipedia article on singular values and singular value decomposition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition

Comment: Thanks. I have read the article. It seems singular values are not exactly square roots of eigenvalues, though.